# I am facing this error AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed" in Android Studio for navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android

This screen shot contains my drawable folder where all pictures are files are defined but when I run my project it shows resource linking failed for All navigation drawer requirements or pictures:

[image]

Here is screen shot of my error build Tab

[image]

**Side_nav_bar.xml code**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
    android:startColor="#ff2d9a59"
    android:centerColor="#ff42959a"
    android:endColor="#ff23729a"
    android:angle="135" />
</shape>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/home_pic"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_become_a_fixer"
            android:icon="@drawable/become_a_fixer_1"
            android:title="Become a fixer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_find_a_fixer"
            android:icon="@drawable/find_a_fixer_pic"
            android:title="Find a fixer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fixer_profile_preview"
            android:icon="@drawable/fixer_profile_preview"
            android:title="Fixer profile preview" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_work_providing_preview"
            android:icon="@drawable/work_providing_preview"
            android:title="Work providing preview" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Sign_out"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout"
            android:title="Sign out" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think through these 3 way you will solve your error.

1)check your style.xml file  and also check a drawable xml fileif everything is okay than look for 2nd method.
2)check your compileSdk Version if your compileSdk  version is 27 than change it with     28 and sync your project and run again.
3)Add below line in your `gradle.properties` file

```
android.enableJetifier = true
```

Comment: As i said i'm using navigation drawer there is themes.xml file and i think it fine i checked it.         2) my compile sdkVersion is 30.                                                                                                   3)for third point i did't understand where to paste that if you explained clearly

Comment: can you show me the code of become_a_fixer1.xml i think there is an error in your drawable file

Comment: its text is long I'm unable to send it

Comment: Okay than check 14th number line of become_a_fixer1.xml

Comment: Thank you for your help i trashed this app and started new project.